# Put javascript script element from html into js file

Tags: javascript

So I have been looking into using tradingview ticker on my webpage.

Trading view has been nice enough to tell me that all I need to do is copy this snippet into my webpage

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Ticker Tape</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js" async>
  {
  "symbols": [
    {
      "proName": "FOREXCOM:SPXUSD",
      "title": "S&P 500"
    }
  ],
  "showSymbolLogo": true,
  "colorTheme": "light",
  "isTransparent": false,
  "displayMode": "adaptive",
  "locale": "en"
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

However I am not content with this. I would like to include everything in the `script` tag in js file.

So the question is, given that I have `index.js` file which is completely empty btw, how do I put

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js" async>
      {
      "symbols": [
        {
          "proName": "FOREXCOM:SPXUSD",
          "title": "S&P 500"
        }
      ],
      "showSymbolLogo": true,
      "colorTheme": "light",
      "isTransparent": false,
      "displayMode": "adaptive",
      "locale": "en"
    }
      </script>
```

into it?

Comment: Have you attempted to add the code to a js file and link it to your html file? If so did you get any issues/errors? What have you attempted thus far?

Comment: The script element in question actually has src link. That's why I am confused. How do I include the src element of it in js file?

Comment: Have you tried adding it as you would a JS library? `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-ticker-tape.js" async>`  have you reached out to trading view? They have a form to contact them on their website.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `<script …>` and `</script>` lines from the last code snippet in your question, put that in the `index.js` file, add `<script src="path/to/index.js></script>` (if you don't already have that somewhere), and it should work fine. If it doesn't, please update your question with any error messages that appear in the console.